# Angular 2 router parameters issue multiple http calls

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-http

I have a route in Angular where I pass an `id` to load an element from my database. In my component I load the element using the following code:

```
this.route.params
        .map((params: Params) => params['id'])
        .switchMap((id: number) => this.service.getElement(id))
        .catch((e) => {
            return Observable.throw(e);
        })
        .subscribe((data: Models.IElement) => {
            this.element= data as Models.IElement;
            this.setTitle();
        }, () => this.router.navigate(['/']));
```

Where `this.service.getElement(id)` makes an http call and returns an Observable. It all goes well. The problem I have now is that I want to issue a second http call and I don't know where to add the code for the second service http call (it would be a similar method to `getElement`, receiving an `id` as parameter).

**More info:** The second http call would ideally be issued in parallel to the `getElement` call. It only depends on the `id` from the `Params`.

How can I make this work using Observables? Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Where do you want to make that second call ? On what is it based ? On previous response ? the route params id ? Give more info please

Comment: It's only based on the id. Ideally it would be issued in parallel to the getElement call.

Comment: I don't have time to give you a solution right now, but take a look into [Fork Join](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-forkJoin), it's the equivalent of `Promise.all`. It'll subscribe to every Observables you pass, and then will wait for every one of them to finish before continuing. Of course, they're launched in parallel. I let you try something and later if don't succeed I'll help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @Maxime's comment I came with the following code:

```
this.route.params
        .map((params: Params) => params['id'])
        .switchMap((id: number) => {
            this.id = id;
            return Observable.forkJoin([this.service.getElem(id), this.service.getElemDocs(id)]);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            return Observable.throw(e);
        })
        .subscribe(([elem, documents]) => {
            this.elem= elemas Models.IElement;
            this.elemDocuments = documents;
            this.setTitle();
        }, () => this.router.navigate(['/']));
```

This launches both calls at the same time and waits for completition from both.